# Read string until find character, skip it and read the next string

Tags: c, csv, input

I'm trying to write a function that receives an input in the following format:

> samplestring1;samplestring2;samplestring3;

Now I'm using this piece of code to read it:

```
scanf("%[^;]",string1);
scanf("%[^;]",string2);
```

But once it reads the first string the next scanf ignores the rest of the input because of the ';' in the way.

There's any solution that uses this kind of scanf "regex alike" format?

Comment: `"%[^;]"` --> `"%[^;];"`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY - How does this work?  I understand the REGEX accepts every character except ; character.  But when you include ; character after the close square bracket, what does that do?

Comment: @Nguaial First, `[ ]` of `scanf` does not match in regular expressions. That is not a regular expression.
`[^ character set ]` allows anything other than the specified character set.
In this case `;` is left as it is not allowed.
You need to consume it by the next input.
The last `;` consumes this as a format.

Comment: What should code do if `samplestring1` consists of 0 characters like `;abc;xyz"?